# Python Selenium click an element if visible

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Python Selenium I am trying to check if an element is visible and then click it if it is...

```
# Check to see if element is visible
    myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='form1']")

    if myelement.is_displayed():
        print (" ")
    else:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='form1']").click
```

This isn't working, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your xpath is correct, you should use `click()`, instead of `click`. It's a method, not an attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems

- `click` is a method, it should be `click()`
- Currently you are trying to click if the button is *not* displayed. It should be

  ```
  if myelement.is_displayed():
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='form1']").click()
  else:
      print (" ")
  ```

You also don't have to relocate the element to click on it

```
myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='form1']")

if myelement.is_displayed():
    myelement.click()
else:
    print (" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is by creating a base class and redefining click and find method and use this instead:

```
from selenium                                 import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui            import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select        import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support               import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by             import By
from abc                                      import abstractmethod




class LocatorMode:

 XPATH = "xpath"
 CSS_SELECTOR = "cssSelector"
 NAME = "name"
 ID = "id"
 TAG_NAME = "tagName"


class BasePage(object):

 def __init__(self, driver):
     self.driver = driver


 def wait_for_element_visibility(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if   locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, Locator)))
     else:
         raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element


 def wait_until_element_clickable(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if   locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Locator)))
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                  until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, Locator)))
     else:
         raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element



 def find_element(self, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if locatorMode == LocatorMode.ID:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.NAME:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_name(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(Locator)
     elif locatorMode == LocatorMode.CSS_SELECTOR:
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Locator)
     else:
        raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element


 def fill_out_field(self, locatorMode, Locator, text):
     self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator).clear()
     self.find_element(locatorMode, Locator).send_keys(text)

 def click(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     self.wait_until_element_clickable(waitTime, locatorMode, Locator).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a try/except:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='form1']").click()  # will click element if visible

except:
    print "Element not visible."
```

Answer (score 0):

is_displayed()  !=  is visible

So, .click() does not work if the element is out of the screen, but is still "displayed"

Correct step is you have to scroll the element into the screen and visible, and then click()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!